# what is messaging queue? why should anyone use in website?

Tags: message-queue

What is messaging queue and why its required?
What will be advantage if we will use messaging queue ?
i have checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decouple front and backend processes in an asynchronous message.

Not something you need for a mom and pop eocommerce shop, but something you use when youa re amazon, for example

Order comes in, submit it to a queue for processing. Have other computers in the back process is async.

This gives ou scalability (multiple backend computers) and resilience (backend down you can still push things into the queue). You can not have scalability or high uptime in these scenarios without a queue based system.

Comment: Thanks @TomTom,  Now I am quite understood

Comment: @nitinjain I have another exception. A software doing financial trading. It reports trades into a queue.... so if the VPN for the trading site is down, or the server in the backoffice resets, execption reports are just delayed.